# Aggregate through entire collection, find duplicate elements between arrays - then print array/json

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out how to aggregate through every Document, inside a Collection.

Each Document has an Array of IPs - how would I proceed to aggregate through each document, and see if ANY IP in 1 document has been found in another?

So it basically just rolls through each array in each document, and then will print out the id that was found with the IPs and then the ips.
**< Example below picture**

I've tried to do a few Aggregations, but since its an array I could only make it basically show true if the full array was identical to an array in a different Document, meaning that even though  2 IP's out of 3 would be found in a different Document, it would not print - because it wasn't identical to the full array.

I know this could be a "speed concern" in the longer run with many Documents, but let that be for now.

[image]

**My wishes:**
Having the ID printed out together with the IP that was found in a different document

only having it print if 2 or more is found.

**How would I get a printout of this - kinda like the example below:**
(IP that was found in multiple document arrays - and what the ID was on that document)

```
{ 
  "82.102.20.247": [
     "113616977779621895", 
     "11361612412495"
   ],

  "12.435.45.20": [
     "113616977124364587", 
     "113616977779621895"
   ],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct `ip` array
- `$group` by `ip` and construct the `id` array, get total count
- `$match` to check total `count` is greater than or equal to 2
- `$group` by null and construct the key-value with `ip` and `ids`
- `$arrayToObject` convert above constructed array to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id: 1,
      ip: 1
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$ip" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$ip",
      ids: { $push: "$id" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $match: { count: { $gte: 2 } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ips: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$ids"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$ips" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fPoZWnsEDXK)

Comment: Thank you so much! Will first return to the pc here in a few hours to test, just replying quick from phone. How about only finding ips that has 2 or higher id results? To kinda avoid the singular ones coming up? I would assume it’s some $gte: 2  .. also i had no idea this website existed, that helps a lot with testing instead of restarting project over & over for changes!

Comment: From the playground it looks much better than my first wants to proceed it - I had thoughts of looping through each document without aggregate to basically write code that does what the aggrevate here does - and it’s much more performance friendly! Thank you so much for the fast answer, I can’t wait to try it out later!